# What am I doing wrong so I always get downvoted?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am new to Stack Overflow, and as of recent, my questions keep on getting downvoted.
They are questions that I have trouble with and I could not find the answer to after hours of research. Could someone explain why people keep downvoting my questions?

I would also like some tips for a newbie like me and others.

Comment: Hours of research for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214617/make-java-exit-out-of-current-program) didn't include Googling "Make java exit out of current program"? Which would have led you to a page literally full of duplicates of the same question (and dozens of answers)? That seems hard to believe.

Comment: Sorry about that, noob at programming, but my other questions are good

Comment: There's nothing wrong with be ing new at something, but basic Googling is expected. Are there other questions that are getting downvoted that you feel are good?

Comment: What I said above also applies to [How do you have java create a random number within two ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212918/how-do-you-have-java-create-a-random-number-within-two-ranges-e-g-5-10-and-12). Googling for the question title yields all the answers you need. Don't ask that kind of thing and you should be fine. :)

Comment: Umm.. yeah: 'About 5,810,000 results'   Research time taken: 4 seconds.

Comment: Did you read [how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @VishvakSeenichamy Pekka's first poke at your questions found that not researched one. I found one with "is this code a valid experiment for this? If not, can you help me write one?" How is this not "too broad"? Have you read the "how to ask" or the help center?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't take all the terse comments posted above too badly. Kudos for asking what's wrong! Most people don't do that.

Newbies at programming are welcome here, but do make sure you have done your research first before asking, and be sure to make it a [good question!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

For two out of the three questions you seem to be referring to ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212918/how-do-you-have-java-create-a-random-number-within-two-ranges-e-g-5-10-and-12) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214617/make-java-exit-out-of-current-program)), basic Googling really is the answer: just entering the question title into Google yields you page upon page of useful results.

Questions like those get downvoted with prejudice on Stack Overflow; they are a waste of everyone's time. Never ask questions like this.

The other downvoted one, [Java Exit Code -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434771/java-exit-code-1), I can't judge because I don't know Java much, but it appears that it is something very basic, perhaps Googleable. <sub>(In fact, when I Google it, I get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1)?)</sub>

I don't really know what you could/should have done to avoid those downvotes, maybe someone else can chime in.

Remember, SO is not a mentoring program; it is a place where (ideally) you ask specific questions that haven't been asked before.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually, being new at something doesn't mean that you cannot ask a good question.

Comment: I think few things to notes is probably what keyword you use to search in google or whatever search engine you used. What code you've tried or link to QA.